# Elasticsearch: _count give strange result

Tags: elasticsearch

$ curl -XGET 'http://test.server.es:9200/index/test/_count?pretty'

```
{
  "count" : 229594,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

try again:

$ curl -XGET 'http://test.server.es:9200/index/test/_count?pretty'

```
{
  "count" : 226967,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

The "count" value is smaller than the previous _count, yet no delete operation between the two _count.

Comment: Are you running it on a multiple nodes cluster?

Comment: Yes. A Cluster of 21 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

One of your nodes went crazy and has uncomplete shards on it.

Ask for stats and find the faulty node:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes/stats'
```

If you had replica set to at least 1, then just stop this node, remove the data dir and restart the node.

My 2 cents

Comment: Thanks. I set number_of_replicas=4, now it's ok.